# Mass verify svn repositories

Tags: svn, corruption, verify, svnadmin

Hi I'm wondering if there is a tool (can be commercial) to mass verify svn repositories. I know about using svnadmin but there are about 100 repositories and it's tedious to check whether if there's actually a corruption. I'm looking for something that can run in the background periodically and alert if there is a corruption.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be reasonably simple to write a shell script that executes `svnadmin verify PATH` for all the repositories, pipes the output to a filter that filters out (e.g. `grep -v`) the normal "Verified revision xxx" cases, and emails the rest to someone? Put that in crontab and you have a periodic mass verifier.

Comment: I'm on windows, and not vaugely familiar with VB. It would take me probably half a day to figure out or do in C#, which cost me more than buying an available solution. Not to mention maintaince.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this doesn't mail the results but it does get it out of all the subversion repos and it doesn't use vb or c#, just plain ol' cmd batch scriptin':

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%s in (*) do svnadmin verify %%s > ..\verified\%%s.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [MR-ATS](http://mr-ats.tigris.org/) which does exactly this thing: It is written in python to help svnadmins by their day to day work (as eg. verify a lot of repositories).

It will work with a scheduled task and send emails, if something strange happens. Additionally it can generate usage reports and do hotcopies for backups.

Answer (score 0):

The MR - ATS tool looks like vapourware.  No released files and no activity for > 1 year :(